# Concatenation in sql statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i concatenate all values from my select statement in one whole string, and how to number them please? For example

```
1. Name Date Price Duration Venue 
2. Name Date Price Duration Venue 
3. Name Date Price Duration Venue


SELECT Film.Title, Film.ParentControl, Program.Venue, 
       Program.Duration, Program.EndDate, Program.Seat
FROM Program 
INNER JOIN Film 
    ON Program.FilmID = Film.FilmID
```

I'm doing an SMS application and i need to send a list of all film to user when they ask for it, each film should listed one by one in a whole message, how can i do that please please?

Comment: You will have to use PL/SQL or T-SQL as you cannot do that simply in SQL.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: the OP is not trying to get a scalar result from concatenating all rows, but simple a concatenation of all columns in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, use the concatenation operator to build the string, and use the row_number() function to number the rows. (But see below . . .)

```
select row_number() over (order by Name, Date) as row_num, 
       Name || ' ' || Date || ' ' || Price || ' ' || Duration || ' ' || Venue 
from your-table-name
order by Name, Date
```

For SQL Server, I think you have to replace the standard concatenation operator ("||") with "+" or use the concat() function.

```
select row_number() over (order by Name, Date) as row_num, 
       concat(Name, Date, Price, Duration, Venue)
from your-table-name
order by Name, Date
```

This is the kind of manipulation that's usually better done in application code. In general, use SQL to return data, and use application code or a report writer to format the data for display.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
declare @result table(title varchar(50), parentcontrol varchar(50), venue varchar(50))
insert into @result
select 'title 1','parent control 1','venue 1'
union all
select 'title 2','parent control 2','venue 2'
union all
select 'title 3','parent control 3','venue 3'

declare @result2 table(id int identity(1,1),title varchar(50), parentcontrol varchar(50), venue varchar(50))

insert into @result2
select * from @result

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = ''

select @sql = @sql + CAST(id as nvarchar(10))  + '. ' + title + ','
from @result2 

print @sql
```

You should be able to work in similar fashion. I am inserting the result, into a variable table having an identity column, to have the row number as well. That is the only purpose of having the ID identity column here since you wanted the row number. Then I am just using normal SQL concatenation. If I understood correctly, this is what you are after.

Comment: *"Then I am just using normal SQL concatenation."* Normal SQL concatenation is "||". Normal SQL *Server* concatenation is "+".

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' yes this answer is MSSQL specific.